# Utilizar variables php en css

Tags: php, css, css3

Tengo un problema. 
Estoy guardando variables php en una base de datos y quiero utilizar esas variables en un archivo css para cuando lo cargue con html use esos valores guardados. Normalmente estas variables son códigos hexadecimales.

En css puedo cargar estas variables de la base de datos por medio de php y otorgarles un valor por ejemplo:

En la base de datos tengo una variable $color1 = #ffffff
En mi css
div {
 color: $color1
}

¿Es posible esto?
¿Cómo se haría sino?

Comment: Mira como Dice [Alvaro](http://es.stackoverflow.com/users/250/alvaro-montoro) Revisate este Articulo [https://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/](https://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/) aunque quizas puedas buscarte otra solución

Answer (score 6):

Claro que es posible. La manera más simple sería tener tu CSS en un fichero PHP que enlazarías directamente como una hoja de estilos normal. Por ejemplo:

**css.php**

```
<?php 
    $azul = "blue"; 
?>
p {
    color: <?php echo $azul; ?>;
    margin:50px;
}
```

**index.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css.php" />
<p>Azul</p>
```

---

Aunque eso funcionará, no sería del todo correcto porque el servidor estaría devolviendo PHP en lugar de CSS (lo que podría llevar a algún tipo de problemas de compatibilidad). Para evitar esto, deberías añadir una línea al principio de `css.php` para indicar que el contenido devuelto es CSS:

```
header('Content-type: text/css');
```

Con eso ya consigues lo que buscas pero, como en los anuncios de televisión: "*¡aún hay más!*". Eso funciona, sí; pero los usuarios pueden ver que estás sirviendo CSS a través de PHP (porque pueden ver la extensión del fichero) y es una información que no necesitan saber (mientras menos información tengan los usuarios y los "chicos malos" sobre la arquitectura de tu sitio web, mejor).

Por eso, como último paso (no necesario), te recomendaría que actualizases la redirección para enmascarar `css.php` como si fuera un fichero .css real. Algo como esto en el `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule css.css css.php [L]
```

Entonces tu PHP se servirá como CSS, y además los usuarios lo verán como si fuese un fichero CSS real (aunque internamente es PHP).

---

Así, los dos ficheros iniciales, más el cambio en `.htaccess` indicado arriba, quedarían de este modo:

**css.php**

```
<?php 
    header('Content-type: text/css');
    $azul = "blue"; 
?>
p {
    color: <?php echo $azul; ?>;
    margin:50px;
}
```

**index.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css.css" />
<p>Azul</p>
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule css.css css.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que dices así sin mas, únicamente puedes utilizar estilos en línea, por ejemplo:

```
<span style="background-color:<?php $color1; ?>">Texto que sea</span>
```

Comment: Y si deseo una hoja entera que cambie esa variable y se guarde esa varieble?

Comment: Tienes que definir el CSS en el mismo fichero, no en una hoja css aparte.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez sea muy específico el caso, pero mi idea en cuanto a esto sería crear hojas de estilos a manera de temas para la web, y almacenar el nombre del tema, de esa manera al cargar la web, pues en el header de la misma completaría la ruta de los archivos css en base al tema seleccionado o habilitado, ya sea para un usuario o para el público.

`$temaActivo` cargaría desde la BD el tema actual.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ruta/temas/<?php echo $temaActivo; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Le puse al header.php antes del cierre del head esto:

```
<?php include('css/header.php'); ?>
```

y el header que está dentro de la carpeta css metí todo el css entre las etiquetas style