# ¿Se puede crear un xml en un archivo .xml y la ayuda de php?

Tags: php, xml

Buenas comunidad, tengo una duda, he creado una vista xml desde un archivo con extensión .php, pero me gustaría saber si, ¿Puedo replicar lo que he hecho pero desde un archivo .xml?. Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
    <?php
$html = "";
$url = "https://sports.yahoo.com/soccer/mls/rss.xml?shangrila=1";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

header("content-type: text/xml");
echo('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>');
// $html .= '  <rss version="2.0">'; // si descomentas se verá como un rss
$html .= '    <channel>';
foreach ($xml->channel as $object) {
  $html .='       <title> '.$object->title.' </title>'; // cabecera
  $html .='       <description> '.$object->description.' </description>';

}

  for($i=0; $i<10;$i++){ // cantidad de noticias
  $title = $object->item[$i]->title;
  $link =  $object->item[$i]->link;
  $description = $object->item[$i]->description;
  $pubDate = $object->item[$i]->pubDate;
  $guid = $object->item[$i]->guid;

  $html .='<item>';
  $html .='       <title> '.$title.' </title>';
  $html .='       <link> '.$link.' </link>';
  $html .='       <description>'.$description.' </description>';
  $html .='       <pubDate> '.$pubDate.' </pubDate>';
  $html .='       <guid> '.$guid.' </guid>';
  $html.='</item>';
}
    $html .= " </channel>";
  // $html .= "      </rss>";
//
  echo $html;
  file_put_contents("rss.xml",$html);
 ?>
```

PD: si quieren ver el código que he creado me hacen saber y lo coloco.

Comment: ¿Qué significa eso de replicar lo que has hecho? ¿Qué has hecho? ¿Podrías explicar mejor qué es lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: Juan, se mas especifico en lo que intentas hacer y con un ejemplo sera genial.

Comment: Creo que lo que buscas es [algo similar a esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/47983/250) pero con XML en lugar de CSS como en esa respuesta.

Comment: por fa, agrega el codigo para entender un poco mas tu pregunta

Comment: Disculpen la tardanza , no había podido leer las respuestas. ya coloqué el código.

Comment: Cuando me refiero a replicar lo que he hecho, significa, que, me gustaría hacer lo que realice con mi código en el archivo .php , pero en uno de extensión .xml , es parecido a la respuesta que colocó @AlvaroMontoro.
Supongo que es un procedimiento totalmente diferente , por eso pregunto.